# Echoing oldest timestamp of a query

Tags: php, mysql

For this simple query, how do I echo out the `datecommented` timestamp (in minutes) of the oldest `loginid`?

```
$queryuidcount = "select loginid, datecommented from comment where (HOUR(NOW()) -       HOUR(datecommented)) <= 1 and loginid = '$uid'"; 
$uidresult = mysql_query($queryuidcount);
```

Comment: Wait, so do you want the oldest `datecommented` or the oldest `loginid`, which I assume is a foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask MySQL to give you the rows in a particular order:

```mysql
  SELECT loginid, datecommented 
    FROM comment 
   WHERE (HOUR(NOW()) - HOUR(datecommented)) <= 1 
     AND loginid = '$uid' 
ORDER BY datecommented ASC
   LIMIT 1 -- use this if you only want 1 row (ie: the oldest row)
```

[MySQL Reference: Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)